# Find a point on a line, a certain distance from a certain point on that line in c program

Tags: c, math, coordinates, line, points

I have given a two point(a[], b[]) which is d(mod) in length. I want to create a function that is able to output a point at n*distance where n is float number (1.5d,0.5d,2d).  I have able to  calculate the gradient and distance between a line but I dont know how to find a point along a line at n*d away form the initial co-ordinate.

```
> #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float modulus(float vec[])
{
  float mod,int i,int n; 
  n = 2; mod = 0.0; 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    mod = mod + (vec[i] * vec[i]);
  }
  mod = sqrt(mod);
  return mod;
}

void diff(float a[], float b[], float c[])
{
  int i; 
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    c[i] = a[i] - b[i];

}


float gradient(float a[], float b[])
{
    int i;
    float dx = a[0]-b[0];
    float dy = a[1]-b[1];
    return (dy/dx);
}


int main()
{
  float a[] = {1., 1.};
  float b[] = {5., 3.}; 
  float c[2]; 
  float len; 
  diff(a, b, c);

  len = modulus(c);
  printf("length = %.2f\n", len); 
  printf("\n gradient of a line : %.2f\n",gradient(a,b));
  return 0;

> `Blockquote`
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of formulas that you can use for this type of linear interpolation (or extrapolation, when d > 1 or d < 0):

```
void lerp_2(float a[], float b[],
            float d,
            float c[])
{
    c[0] = a[0] + (b[0] - a[0]) * d;
    c[1] = a[1] + (b[1] - a[1]) * d;
}
```

Or

```
void lerp_2(float a[], float b[],
            float d,
            float c[])
{
    c[0] = a[0] * (1.0f - d) + b[0] * d;
    c[1] = a[1] * (1.0f - d) + b[1] * d;
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/BoVh6K), a testable implementation.

Comment: This is the correct solution, based on linear algebra and the lever rule.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need gradient (slope).

In your case you are given n - ratio between new vector and difference vector, so calculations are simple:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    result[i] = a[i] + n * c[i];
```

for n=0.5 new point will lie in the middle betwwen a and b

In general case of arbitrary distance you need to calculate normalized (unit length) direction vector

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    u[i] = c[i] / len;
```

and multiply it's components by needed distance

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    result[i] = a[i] + u[i] * needed_distance;
```